# Issue with converting datetime to Integer

Tags: php

I am facing issue with converting datetime string to integer. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$date = date("y:m:d h:i:s"); // string.
$date2 = strtotime($date); // Boolean value. not converted to integer.
echo $date2;
```

Comment: It's because of the non-standard format - if you use `y-m-d` it will work.

Comment: Thanks. it worked.

Comment: tip, use UTC instead (thoughout) then convert later into whichever timezone is needed, else your need to handle daylight savings

Answer (score 0):

replace the : to -

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$date = date("y-m-d h:i:s"); // string.
$date2 = strtotime($date); // Boolean value. not converted to integer.
echo $date2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code may be simplified as the following one-liner:

```
<?php

// 'U' will return UNIX timestamp
echo (new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London')))->format('U');
```

Answer (score 0):

date("Y-m-d H:i:s") supplies the current time as string.
strtotime with the current time provides a current timestamp.
The [time()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function does just that. It returns the current Unix timestamp as integer.

```
$currentUnixTimestamp = time();
//echo time();
```